# Using Dim'ed Range In Email Body

Tags: vba, string, outlook, range

Trying to reference a dynamic range in the body of an email (this will change based on the user's input into the sheet).  The email outputs just fine, but there is nothing in the email where "AFund" is supposed to be.  Code is below, any help is appreciated!

```
Dim BlasEmail As Workbook
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim FundAdd, FundRem, Broker As Range
Dim AFund As String

Set BlastEmail = ActiveWorkbook
Set Cover = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cover")
Set CDEA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CDEA")

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
LasRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row



FundAdd = AFund
Set FundAdd = Range("E2:E" & LastRow)

Set FundRem = Range("G2:G" & LRow)
Set Broker = Range("C6:C" & LasRow)

If Range("ISDAMRA") = "ISDA" And Range("G2") = "" Then

Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\My Signature.htm"
    
                   
    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
Dim EmBody As String

    EmBody = "Hello," & "<br><br>" & _
              "Body goes here " & "<br>" & "<br>" & AFund
    
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = "myemail"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Here is the subject " & Range("B6") & " "
                .HTMLBody = EmBody & Signature
                'You can add files like this
                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                '.Send
                .Display 'This will display the emails for the user to review CXH

            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing

End If

'
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, in your example the line that adds the range is commented out. `'& Range("ISDADATE") & " with " & Range("LongName") & _`

Comment: Thanks, I removed that, was just testing where the issue was so I commented it out.  I've tried to use FundAdd (which is the dynamic range) instead of AFund, but get a type mismatch when I try that.

Comment: You don't assign any value to `AFund`

Comment: When I try to set AFund = FundAdd, it doesn’t let me add that range to EmBody.  I’ve tried moving AFund under FundAdd, but no dice.

Comment: You can't add `someRange.Value` to a string if `someRange` isn't a single cell: the `Value` of a multi-cell range is a 2D array, not a simple value.

Comment: So should I dim something as array, then set that array to = FundAdd?

Answer (score 0):

From:

- [Sending a range of cells...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73136067)
- [2 Methods to Quickly Send Selected Cells in an Excel Worksheet as an Outlook Email](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-methods-quickly-send-selected-cells-excel-worksheet-outlook-email/)

```vb
Option Explicit '  Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub SendRange()
    
    ' https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-methods-quickly-send-selected-cells-excel-worksheet-outlook-email/
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73136067
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    ' Application is Excel. No influence in Outlook.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Reference Microsoft Outlook nn.n Object Library
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
    
    ' Reference Microsoft Word nn.n Object Library
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    
    Dim strGreeting As String
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print lastRow

    Dim fundAdd As Range
    Dim objSelection As Range
    Set fundAdd = Range("E2:E" & lastRow)
    fundAdd.Select
    
    Set objSelection = Selection
    objSelection.Copy
    
    Dim objTempWorkbook As Workbook
    Set objTempWorkbook = Workbooks.Add(1)
    
    Dim objTempWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set objTempWorksheet = objTempWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 
    Dim strTempHTMLFile As String, Strbody As String
    Dim objTempHTMLFile As Object, objTextStream As Object
 
    Dim objFileSystem As Object
    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    'Pasting into a Temp Worksheet
     With objTempWorksheet.Cells(1)
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
     End With
 
    'Save the Temp Worksheet as a HTML File
    strTempHTMLFile = objFileSystem.GetSpecialFolder(2).Path & _
      "\Temp for Excel" & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD hh-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    Set objTempHTMLFile = objTempWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, _
      strTempHTMLFile, objTempWorksheet.Name, objTempWorksheet.UsedRange.Address)
    objTempHTMLFile.Publish (True)
    
    strGreeting = "Hello," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
      "Body goes here " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With olEmail
                
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector  ' A side effect is to get the signature
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
                      
        wdDoc.Range.InsertBefore strGreeting
        wdDoc.Paragraphs(5).Range.Paste
                    
        'Insert the Temp Worksheet into the Email Body
        Dim wb1 As Workbook
        Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
        
        Dim TempFilePath As String
        TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
        
        Dim TempFileName As String
        TempFileName = "Output Data"
        
        Dim FileExtStr As String
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx"
        
        Debug.Print TempFilePath & TempFileName
        wb1.SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        
        .Display
        
    End With

    objTempWorkbook.Close (False)
    objFileSystem.DeleteFile (strTempHTMLFile)
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr 'Delete the temp Excel File

    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olEmail = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```